# How can I disable Android 4.0 home button?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I can disable home button for Android 2.2, 3.0 etc. But same code does not work for 4.0. Is there any solution to disable home button?

```
@Override 
public void onAttachedToWindow() 
{ 
    super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD); 
}
```

Comment: Not recommended to disable home button. But if anyone are to help you, you should first show the code that doesn't work for 4.0

Comment: @Override
 public void onAttachedToWindow() {
     super.onAttachedToWindow();
     this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
 }

Comment: @Trakyali, Comments like that are unreadable, you should delete your comment and edit your question adding this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disabling the Home Button**, many developers ask about such a feature!! but all I can say: you should absolutely not be disabling the home button in an Android application. This is a major **anti-pattern**, and will both make your app labelled as **spammy** and **malware-like**. Users hate when you disable their home button, and you should really avoid it at all costs. It's not against the law to do this , but your users will get pissed off and you will get a low ratings on google play for your app. Also This technique **no longer** works in **Android 4.0**, for obvious **security** reasons!!

Comment: You are right but i want to make a launcher and i need this feature.

Comment: @Trakyali You don't need to disable home button in order to make a launcher.

Comment: How about customized android tablets used for public access? It's definitely a necessary feature.

Answer (score 3):

u can simply add following code to ur android manifest:

```
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />              
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />                 
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />               
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
```