# Disable Home button in Android 4.0+

Tags: android, home-button

I'm trying to replace the stock lock screen with my own app.
In my code, i want to disable the Home button.
I know how to do this in Android 2.3 and below,
but the same code doesn't work with Android 4.0+ (return to desktop when Home button pressed)

Recently I found out an app called MiHome which has its own lock screen and is able to disable the Home button.
Does anyone know how it achieves this???

Answer (score 15):

There is no way to intercept the home button on Android, unless you make your app the home screen. This is for security reasons, so that malicious apps cannot take over your device by overriding all the buttons that can exit. The home button is the one sure shot way to be able to leave any app.

If you want to handle the HOME button, implement a home screen.

Answer (score 3):

Mucking with the home button is disabled for security/reliability reasons in ICS. (Most apps use it for evil than good)

Please refer to the following questions for workarounds.

1. [how can I disable android 4.0 home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394843/how-can-i-disable-android-4-0-home-button)
2. [override Home key in android ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025660/override-home-and-back-button-is-case-a-boolean-is-true/10025904#10025904)
3. [Disable Home Button in Android ICS (4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077675/disable-home-button-in-android-ics-4-0)

Seems like the only way is to implement a home screen

Comment: this approach does not work on Android 4.0.3  comment by commonsware for the second link.

Comment: Sorry bout that. Seems like this is not possible on ICS without implementing a fake home screen. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            } else {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            }
    mOverlay = (RelativeLayout) inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.main, (ViewGroup) null);

    mOverlay.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mWindowManager.addView(mOverlay, params);
```