# how can I disable home button in android.I am writing an screen lock app but cannot disable the home button

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I am writing a screen lock app for `android.Overriding` <kbd>back</kbd> button , power button is fine.

But it seems that we cannot disable home button.

Is there any way out to disable <kbd>home</kbd> button?

Comment: please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459407/disable-home-button-in-android-4-0), it is not possible to override home-button anymore.

Comment: Can you suggest some good tutorials for implementing home screen in android , through which i could finally write my screen lock app.

Comment: No.. I haven't checked for home screen, yet.