# How create fullscreen in android 4.0?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

**Hello,**
I need do fullscreen in android 4.0 (I must hide back button, home...)
I used `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`
but it doesn't work.

Comment: where did you put this line ? you should put this in your <Activity> tag as an attribute in your manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Homebutton and backbutton cannot be hidden...
Users always need to have access to these buttons, so the black bar will always be on the screen

Answer (score 1):

Like write K_Anas in a [relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394843/how-can-i-disable-android-4-0-home-button), it is not possible hide Homebutton and backbutton in Android 4.0, for security reasons and because is a simply anti-pattern solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) to hide the system navigation temporarily, but it will always reappear when the user touches the screen. Even the notification bar will reappear when the screen is touched.

You are not allowed to hide the system bar with the home button completely for security reasons.