# How do I disable Home button in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-homebutton, android-hardware, home-button

In my app i have to disable device's Home key, my tab supports android 4.4.2

I know how to disable back button functionality, i used below lines for that

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

but i am concern about `How to disable Home button functionality ?`

I tried below code to disable home button but did not get any help

```
// to disable home button -- START --   
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
// to disable home button -- END --
```

Comment: take a look at this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2080353/3326331), you can try overriding `onKeyDown()` for keyCode `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME`, but its highly unreliable, sometimes the method is not called for Home Button

Comment: but any how I have to disable home button

Comment: try [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14601640/2884893) this it worked on my 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `onKeyDown()`

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        Log.d("Test", "Home button pressed!");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> No.... You cannot override home button for Android4.0 and above

This is for security reasons.

---

[Check this answer from Commonsware for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10350208/1083093)

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano, this definitively provides an answer to the question …

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano  ...... This is a correct answer, i have tested this !

Comment: ok, gotcha! Sorry for the fuss then. I'll remove the comment

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
    // put your logic here.
     }
return true;
}
```

or you can try this:

```
ActionBar actionBar;
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```