# Disable home button in android 4.x

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-homebutton

As I am developing an app for kids, I need to disable home button so that they won't close the app on class.
Anyone know how to disable it in android 4.X?
(The home button is a real one but not virtual button on screen)

Comment: did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394843/how-can-i-disable-android-4-0-home-button

Comment: look this post answer on stackoverflow                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
According to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME) the home button isn't delivered to applications and handled by framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in **rooted** devices.

This is what I did for that:

```
package com.juanjovega.examples;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

public class KioskActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Work around an Android 2.3 bug that sometimes causes us to become
        // invisible after turning the display off and on with the power button.
        setVisible(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void setFullScreen(boolean fullscreen) {
        Process proc = null;

        String ProcID = "79"; // HONEYCOMB AND OLDER

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            ProcID = "42"; // ICS AND NEWER
        }

        try {
            if (fullscreen) {
                proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c service call activity " + ProcID + " s16 com.android.systemui");
                Log.d("kiosk", "Fullscreen mode ON");
            } else {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am startservice --user 0 -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");
                Log.d("kiosk", "Fullscreen mode OFF");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    // Override the default Back key action so that we don't lose control.
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("kiosk", "onBackPressed");
    }

    public void clearHomeConfig() {
        Log.d("kiosk", "clearHomeConfig");

        getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());
    }

    public void exitApp() {
        // Restore UI.
        setFullScreen(false);

        // Clear home config.
        getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());

        // Exit
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this working (in unity3D, through a plugin), but I haven't tested it in many devices, just a nexus tablet. The device must be rooted, otherwise you can't work start/stop services, and it makes the app fullscreen, not just disables home button. It was the best option I found.